# Scala : how to start an actor in array?

Tags: java, arrays, scala, translate, actor

I'm trying to write a simple client/server chat application in 2 languages - Java and Scala. Java version is working and the only problem is to translate it. 
In Java i have code like this:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileServer666 extends Thread{

    static Socket clientSocket = null;
    static ServerSocket  serverSocket= null;    
    static  clientThread t[] = new clientThread[10]; 

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException           
    { 
        int port_number =1406;
        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number);
        }catch(IOException e){System.out.println(e);}

        System.out.println("Listening" +port_number);

        while(true)
        {
            try
            {           
                clientSocket=serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Akceptuje połaczenie od: "+clientSocket.getInetAddress());

                for(int i=0; i<=9; i++)
                {               
                    if(t[i]==null)                                  
                    {
                        (t[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket,t)).start();
                        break;
                    }
                }                       
            }catch(IOException e){System.out.println(e);}       
        }
    }       
}
```

Here I have a problem. How to translate this line into Scala:

```
(t[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket,t)).start();
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep to a direct translation and your problem is just that assigning does not return a value in scala, then just do

```
t(i) = new ClientThread(clientSocket, t)
t(i).start
```

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. Every time I run client application i have nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
t(i) = ( new ClientActor( clientSocket, t) ).start
```

where `ClientActor` is your actor.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I have error:
type mismatch; found : scala.actors.Actor required: server.Wyslij
Wyslij is my actor.